# Make a generator of models inheriting from a pre-built model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a little Ruby on Rails CMS, and I want to make a generator that would create models inheriting from the pre-built CMS data model. For example, I have a `Entry` model in my CMS, and I want to create a `Post` model that would be child of this model. This is the source code:

**db/migrations/*create_mycms_entries.rb**:

```
class CreateMyCmsEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :my_cms_entries do |t|
      t.string :type, index: true
      t.string :title
      t.string :slug, index: true
      t.json :payload
      t.integer :user_id, index: true
      t.string :author_name

      t.datetime :published_at
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**entry.rb**:

```
module MyCms
  class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :published, -> { where('published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now) }

    def self.content_attr(attr_name, attr_type = :string)
      content_attributes[attr_name] = attr_type

      define_method(attr_name) do
        self.payload ||= {}
        self.payload[attr_name.to_s]
      end

      define_method('#{attr_name}='.to_sym) do |value|
        self.payload ||= {}
        self.payload[attr_name.to_s] = value
      end
    end

    def self.content_attributes
      @content_attributes ||= {}
    end
  end
end
```

and, at my blog side, **post.rb**:

```
class Post < MyCms::Entry
  content_attrs :body, :text

  # Rest of the stuff...
end
```

I want the final command look something like this:

```
$ rails generate entry Post body:text
```

But I'm not quite sure I know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create custom model generator then you can use Thor (https://github.com/erikhuda/thor) which rails team has documented here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

First start by typing this command:

```
bin/rails g generator entry
```

So you are triggering generator to generate generator :). You will get something like this after running your command

```
create  lib/generators/entry
create  lib/generators/entry/entry_generator.rb
create  lib/generators/entry/USAGE
create  lib/generators/entry/templates
```

Then what you can do is just copy the code that ActiveRecord has for creating models. Inside your templates you will have this file model.rb like here

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/templates/model.rb

You will see that it has something like this:

```
class <%= class_name %> < <%= parent_class_name.classify %>
```

class_name is a variable that you pass to your generator, like in your example Post. And you can define it like this inside your entry_generator

```
argument :class_name, type: :string, default: "Post"
```

I would definitely recommend that you look at this file since the rails generator has everything you need...you would just customize it for your specific need:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb

In generator you have a class that invokes the template. Here is another video from Ryan Bytes that explains creating generator on custom layout which you can find it useful for your CMS.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is single-table inheritance (STI) and Rails has the support for that. Basically you need column `type` in your `entries` table which would store the class name within your hierarchy. You don't need to use the parent attribute as it seems to be in your example. See more in [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) or blogs, e.g. [this one](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=4).